# Visual Studio 2010 can't locate <iostream>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iostream

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 and I have a feeling something went pretty awry while I was installing it.  I have the following code return an error stating that it can't find the <iostream> file.  I looked in the includes folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include) and I only saw 4 files (omp.h, pgobootrun.h, srv.h, wmiatlprov.h).  I'm not sure if that's normal, but I'm 99% sure it's not.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Which returns the following errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 06/11/2012 0:31:05.
1>PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "c:\users\jake\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Test2\Debug\".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\Test2.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  Test2.cpp
1>c:\users\jake\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\test2.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>c:\users\jake\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test2\test2\stdafx.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
1>  Generating Code...
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

No matter how many Google searches I make I can't figure out how to resolve the issue.  Any help is appreciated.  If any more detail is needed, I can provide anything required for solving this, thank you.

**EDIT 1:** I'm not using a precompiled header. I downloaded it from the MSDN website on a page I can't post here because it's tied to the account, but I definitely didn't run out of room (I have around 650 GB free on my hard drive).  Yes, I tried re-installing (at least 4 times).

**EDIT 2:** The page tied to my account was from the Microsoft website.  Step-by-step what I did was download the .iso, extract it to a folder with 7zip, run the autorun.exe file, go through with installation (Couldn't have been any errors there, all I did was check the "Privacy Policy" boxes and whatnot), opened up Visual Studio, typed in the code that I have below, and run it.  I didn't think that needed any explanation.

Comment: Seems something went wrong, I have 206 elements in my `include` folder

Comment: Could you post a link to what you downloaded/installed? Looks like something that would happen from running out of space on the drive too, depending what else is missing.

Comment: Are you using a precompiled header in Microsoft Visual Studio? If so, can you show us that too?

Comment: If you don't explain step by step exactly what you did, nobody can help you. Also, `on a page I can't post here because it's tied to the account` tied to what account?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should try reinstalling or just simply perform a repair in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried redownloading it? Or - since you said that you've downloaded it from a page that's tied to your account - how about downloading it from microsoft.com?

Comment: The page that was tied to my account was on the Microsoft website.

Comment: How about downloading the service pack 1? Here's the link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691